# How to get notified when SwiftUI's ShareLink view is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In iOS 16, when can use `ShareLink` to present a share sheet. Is there a way to get notified when user swipe down or close this view? Need to do something after the share sheet is dismissed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `onDisappear { }` on the `ShareLink` view?

Comment: @user1046037 that's a good guess. But onDisappear will actually be called once the ShareLink is pressed. It has nothing todo with the sheet disappear or not. Guess Apple need to refine the logic here.

Comment: could you post some code, always post minimum code so that others are on the same page

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this too. As far as I can tell, `ShareLink` doesn't yet have a way to run code on dismiss. What worked very well for me was adapting `UIActivityViewController` for SwiftUI, and then presenting the share view in a sheet.

```
struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}

}
```

Usage:

```
Button(action: {
    presentShareSheet = true
}) {
    Text("Share Link")
}
.sheet(isPresented: $presentShareSheet, onDismiss: { 
    // Code to run on dismiss
}) {
    ActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Check out this link!", URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!])
}
```